# My HUAWEI router does not seem to open all the ports that is set to open without giving me any relevant output. Why so?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, ufw

Some of my ports that I reckon I did my best to open them do not appear to be open for [canyouseeme](https://canyouseeme.org/).
For example, I get this from the website (I replaced my public IP with wildcard characters for privacy reasons):

```
Error: I could not see your service on ***.***.**.*** on port (6256)
Reason: Connection timed out.
```

The port seems to be closed indeed as my **i2pd** webconsole seems to confirm:

```
Network status: Firewalled
```

I have a bash script that is run every minute by cron acting as root. The purpose of the script is to open and close ports
on my PC in response to the apps that I start or close.

```
/usr/bin/pgrep -f /home/jerzy/bitcoin/bin/bitcoind
if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then

 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 8333 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
 
  
else

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 8333 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload

 
 
fi

/usr/bin/pgrep i2p-zero

if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then

 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 12714 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
 
else

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 12714 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
 
fi


/usr/bin/pgrep ipfs

if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then

 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 4001 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
else

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 4001 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
fi


/usr/bin/pidof transmission-daemon

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
 
 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 51413 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload

else 

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 51413 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload

fi

/usr/bin/pgrep -f /home/jerzy/monero-x86_64-linux-gnu/monerod

if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then

 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 18080 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
else

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 18080 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
fi

/usr/bin/pgrep -f /usr/sbin/i2pd #the paths are different for Arch and for Ubuntu, thats why do not use pgrep -f

 if [[ "$?" == 0 ]]; then

 /usr/sbin/ufw allow 6256  && /usr/sbin/ufw reload #selected by me in /var/lib/i2pd/i2pd.conf
 
 
 else

 /usr/sbin/ufw deny 6256 && /usr/sbin/ufw reload
 
 fi
```

Now, on the side of my router I set the following:

First I went to **Advanced settings>LAN>DHCP Static IP Configuration**
and made sure that the internal IP of my laptop does not get changed:
[image]

Then I set the particular polices and applied them:

This is the policy for **transmission** and port 51413.
[image]
This is the policy for **monero** and port 18080.
[image]
For privacy reasons not all can be viewed in the screenshots, but the only differences between the policies are their names and the port numbers to which they apply.

The issue as of now is that the ports other than 51413 do not appear to be open on [canyouseeme](https://canyouseeme.org/). All the ports specified in the script
used to be open a couple of months ago. Then in June of this year I noticed that despite not having changed anything in my script or in the settings of the router,
all the ports, including 51413, appeared to be closed on for **canyouseeme**.
Resetting the router settings only slightly improved my situation, port 51413 is now verified by **canyouseeme** as open, but with respect
to the other ports they still appear to be closed. As of now I have transmission, **monerod** and **i2pd** running and my script apears to have opened the respective ports for me
as evidenced by the output of `sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8333                       DENY        Anywhere                  
12714                      DENY        Anywhere                  
4001                       DENY        Anywhere                  
51413                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
18080                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
6256                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8333 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
12714 (v6)                 DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
4001 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
51413 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
18080 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
6256 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Yet when I verify with **canyouseeme** only 51413 is open. One time time it crossed my mind that there may be some sort of limit
of ports being opened on the router. On that thought I tinkered with port-mapping on my router, removing the policy for 51413 and 18080 and
leaving only one policy for port 6256. This to no avail, port 6256 remained closed.

My environment:
Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.
Router [HUAWEI EG8141A](https://e.huawei.com/za/products/enterprise-transmission-access/access/ont/eg8141a5)[5](https://e.huawei.com/za/products/enterprise-transmission-access/access/ont/eg8141a5) with [GPON terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.984) connected to fiber optic internet in Spain. My public IP is `185.144.**,***` and the output of `traceroute 185.144.**,***` is:

```
traceroute to 185.144.**.*** (185.144.**.***), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  185.144.**.*** (185.144.**.***)  1.560 ms  4.337 ms  4.365 ms
```

The ISP is [Redytel](https://www.redytel.info/). I've read [here](https://prefixx.net/news/carrier-grade-nat-windows-10) that if the output of traceroute is a list of one element that one is not behind [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).
Given the output of the `traceroute` and the fact that my public IP does not begin with *10* or *100* I reckon I'm not behind CGNAT.

My questions are?
What factors can be at play? Censorship of the ISP?
Can the ports in fact be forwarded but for some reason resistant to scanning by the port scanner?
How might I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Are you behind a CGNAT?

Comment: @Ramhound I reckon I'm not beging CGNAT - my public IP begins with 185. . I'm not sure how to check whether I'm behind CGNAT, my router's GUI does not show other IPs than those internal IPs of the devices connected to the network.

Comment: If you don't know if you are behind a CGNAT you can always ask your ISP.  It would explain the reason you have been unsuccessful in opening your port and forwarding the traffic on to your device on those ports.

Comment: I have no idea, being able to ping yourself, does not really provide any substantial information

Comment: @Ramhound I added info to the question in response to your comments.